# Entity framework code-first null foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship, entity-framework-4.1

I have a `User` < `Country` model. A user belongs to a country, but may not belong to any (null foreign key).

How do I set this up? When I try to insert a user with a null country, it tells me that it cannot be null.

The model is as follows:

```
 public class User{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country{
    public List<User> Users {get; set;}
    public int CountryId {get; set;}
}
```

Error: `A foreign key value cannot be inserted because a corresponding primary key value does not exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = Country_Users ]"}`

Comment: Can you kindly correct me if i am wrong. A foreign key is NULLABLE by DEFAULT in code first asp.net mvc - 5 entity framework.

Comment: If we want to make it non nullable. we need to either use fluent api if not then decorate with "Required" attribute. Am I correct?

Comment: If we don't do either then Foreign key will be defaulted to Nullable

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You must make your foreign key nullable:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Virtual is necessary for lazy loading.

Comment: Virtual also adds change tracking, which isn't always wanted. About the only time that we ever want virtual is on collections, but YMMV.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - And how would the lazy loading work when an attempt to get a navigation property was made when the id was null (which throws an exception)?

Comment: @TravisJ user.Country returns null then... either catch the exception (optimal) or use `if` (eww)

Comment: Any ideas as to how this translates to vb.net?

Comment: @Jay use `Nullable(Of Integer)` or `Integer?` in vb.net.

Comment: Also -- this doesn't seem to work for `Guid` based keys.  (It makes them nullable, sure, but saving a record to the database with the foreign key set to null fails due to an automatically generated foreign key constraint.) :-(

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I already have a nullable column in my table. Only thing is earlier I didn't need the navigation properties so I didn't add them, so the foreign key is not there. Now I have a requirement to navigate between these two entities. When I tried to add the navigation props, migration is created. But when that migration is applied it gives me following error. "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint" I know this should work and what am I missing?

Comment: I think in asp.net mvc 5 code first convention, foreign keys are nullable by default.

Comment: I prefer this (below):

    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? CountryId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    }

Because EF was creating 2 foreign keys in the database table: CountryId, and CountryId1, but the code about fixed that.

Comment: I stated the `nullable Guid` on my model too and I wasn't noticing any `nullable: true` on my brand new migration. Once applied, checked the relationships on the SMSS and saw it was allowing nulls. My problem was that I was trying to add `Guid.Empty` instead of a `null`

Answer (score 15):

I prefer this (below):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Because EF was creating 2 foreign keys in the database table: CountryId, and CountryId1, but the code above fixed that.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I was having. I don't even have a navigation property in my entity, so it's a bit odd that it's happening anyway.

Answer (score 10):

I have the same problem now ,
I have foreign key and i need put it as nullable,
to solve this problem you should put

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Country>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Users)
        .WithOptional(c => c.Country)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.CountryId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

in DBContext class
I am sorry for answer you very late :)

Comment: 'WithOptional' no linger valid for EFCore... only has 'WithOne'

Answer (score 3):

In EF 7 :

```
entity.Property(e => e.propertyName).IsRequired(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read Microsoft guide for use **Relationships, Navigation Properties and Foreign Keys** in EF Code First, like this picture.

[image]

Guide link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships?redirectedfrom=MSDN