# Entity Framework, Code First: How can i make a Foreign Key Not-Nullable

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship

All possibilities to change the database model with Fluent API i found so far assume that the property which i want to edit exist also as a property in the entity. But i don't know how to change attributes of a property, which is not a property in the entity class.

Example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        this.Addresses = new List<Address>();
    }
}
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Now Code First creates a database where the Addresses table has PersonId as a FK, so having a 1-to-* relationship (what is what i want). But the FK PersonId in Addresses is nullable, and i can't access this FK in Fluent API since there is no property. How can i change this FK to be not-nullable?

Also, at the moment when i want to delete a Person, EF don't let me do this since there is an associated address. I thought the behaviour is:

- nullable FK: delete the record in question, set the child record FK to null
- not-nullable: error, or delete record together with all associated records (depending on cascade rules)

Is this not correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following Fluent API directive did it for me, so to achieve

- 1-to-* relationship
- FK not nullable
- FK not defined as a property in the entity class
- cascade delete (deleting the parent deletes all associated records, here Addresses)

the following statement has to be included in OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(a => a.Addresses).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

For first you must make foreign key nullable.

[Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487577/entity-framework-ef-code-first-cascade-delete-for-one-to-zero-or-one-relations)

For second you will have to use the fluent API to do this.

Try adding the below to your DB Context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.Address)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
```

[For further detail see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668801/entity-framework-code-first-null-foreign-key)

Comment: I'm sorry, i messed up the topic. See the detailed opening post: actually i want a non-nullable FK. For the second: When i use this, Code First wants to drop the FK column on Addresses, and add a FK in the Person table, so i don't have an 1-to-* relationship anymore

Comment: i got it! i'll create an answer and mark it as accepted, although your post gave the inspiration, so thank you!

Comment: Can you kindly tell me if this is expected behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571025/how-to-correctly-set-foreign-key-constraint-in-one-to-many-relationship-in-code/45572561#45572561