# EntityFramework Code First nullable foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I all,

I am trying to get a nullable foreign key but can not get this to work for me.
My model looks like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate the user identity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">The user service</param>
    /// <param name="authenticationType">The autentication type</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserService service, string authenticationType)
    {

        // Create our identity
        var userIdentity = await service.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

        // Return our identity
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

The **CompanyId** is the foreign key that should be null, so in my **DbContext** I have set this mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().HasMany(m => m.Members).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(m => m.CompanyId);
```

But when I run my application I always get an error:

> - InnerException  {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Users_dbo.Companies_CompanyId\". The conflict occurred in database \"melanite\", table \"dbo.Companies\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}   System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

does anyone know how I can change my mapping to work correctly?

Comment: by using `public int? CompanyId { get; set; }` ? (have you seen the **?**)

Comment: Please start with nullable company id
`public int? CompanyId { get; set; }`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668801/entity-framework-code-first-null-foreign-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
```

This will map CompanyId as nullable foreign key

Comment: Can you kindly help me with this related question. Are the **foreign key nullable by default** in code first entity framework approach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571025/how-to-correctly-set-foreign-key-constraint-in-one-to-many-relationship-in-code

Comment: How do we do it, if it was `string` instead of `int`?

Comment: nvm, it turned out I was sending empty string rather than `null`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer:
Nullable types are declared in one of two ways:

System.Nullable variable
-or-

T? variable

T is the underlying type of the nullable type. T can be any value type including struct; it cannot be a reference type.

The following MSDN link provides a good explanation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Company);}
```