# configure related entities with the same key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity type `MyEntity` that has a primary key `string MyEntityCode`

I want to make a second entity `MyEntityInfo` that are extended properties that some `MyEntity`'s are logically associated.

That makes the relationship between these entities one-to-one, with one end optional -- `MyEntity` logically optionally has a `MyEntityInfo`, without a navigation property, and `MyEntityInfo` is required to have a single `MyEntity` (with a navigation property).

I want to encode this in SQL as `MyEntityInfo` having a primary key `BaseEntityCode` that's also a foreign key to `MyEntity`'s `MyEntityCode`.

How do I configure this encoding in EF6 fluent configuration API.

Sample code

```
public class MyEntity {
  public string MyEntityCode {get; set;}
  public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntityInfo {
  public MyEntity BaseEntity {get; set;}
  public string BaseEntityCode {get; set;}
  public int OtherInfo {get; set;}
}

public MyEntityConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<MyEntity> {
  public MyEntityConfiguration(){
    HasKey(e => e.MyEntityCode);
  }
}
```

I thought I could configure `MyEntityInfo` as

```
public MyEntityInfoConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<MyEntityInfo> {
  public MyEntityInfoConfiguration(){
    HasKey(e => e.BaseEntityCode);
    HasRequired(e => e.BaseEntity).WithOptional().WithForeignKey(e => BaseEntityCode);
  }
}
```

but `WithOptional()` doesn't allow chaining to `WithForeignKey`

Doing the same but with `WithMany()` so that a foreign key is possible, the multiplicity constraint of one is violated:

> Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Comment: Why don’t you have MyEntity be the base class of MyEntityInfo?

Comment: @Neil.Work I prefer not to use class inheritance to encode relationships between data. If that's the only way to get the schema I want, then that's how it's going to be, but the encoding rarely has advantages over compositional alternatives IMO.

Comment: @Neil.Work in this specific example, it seems really cumbersome to change an existing MyEntity, and add MyEntityInfo. You'd need a new instance because you need to construct a new subtype to replace the old supertype.

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668801/entity-framework-code-first-null-foreign-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought I could configure MyEntityInfo as
>
> ```
>    public class MyEntityInfoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntityInfo>
>    {
>       public MyEntityInfoConfiguration(){
>         HasKey(e => e.BaseEntityCode);
>         HasRequired(e => e.BaseEntity).WithOptional().WithForeignKey(e => BaseEntityCode);
>       }
>     }
> ```

Well, almost, just remove the `WithForeignKey` call!

```cs
public class MyEntityInfoConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntityInfo>
{
    public MyEntityInfoConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.BaseEntityCode);
        HasRequired(e => e.BaseEntity).WithOptional();
    }
}
```

Entity Framework 6 has only one implementation of 1:1 associations: the primary key of the dependent entity (here: `MyEntityInfo`) is the foreign key to the principal entity (here: `MyEntity`).

There is no `WithForeignKey` method because with your proposed mapping (without `WithForeignKey`) EF knows all it needs to know now for the only implementation of 1:1 it has in store.

The produced database model shows the primary key/foreign key dual role of `BaseEntityCode`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntities] (
    [MyEntityCode] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [SomeProperty] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.MyEntities] PRIMARY KEY ([MyEntityCode])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyEntityInfoes] (
    [BaseEntityCode] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [OtherInfo] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.MyEntityInfoes] PRIMARY KEY ([BaseEntityCode])
)
...
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyEntityInfoes] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.MyEntityInfoes_dbo.MyEntities_BaseEntityCode]
    FOREIGN KEY ([BaseEntityCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MyEntities] ([MyEntityCode])
```