# Navigation Property other than primary key in self referencing table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, one-to-many

I have a table named `Customer` and it has two properties `ReferrerCode` and `OwnReferrerCode`. When a customer registers, he/she can put a referrer code of another customer and the system will assign a unique `OwnReferrerCode`. Multiple customers can use a specific customer's refer code.

```
public class Customer 
{
  [PrimaryKey]
  public long CustomerId {get;set;}
  public string ReferrerCode {get;set;}
  public string OwnReferrerCode {get;set;}

  public Customer ReferrerCustomer { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Customer> ReferredCustomers { get; set; }
}
```

And in config file:

```
this.HasOptional<Customer>(s => s.ReferrerCustomer).WithMany(g => g.ReferredCustomers)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.ReferrerRewardCode);
```

It obviously returns this error
*`The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role.`*

Is there any way to do that kind of relation in **`EF6`**

Answer (score 0):

As you explained, the customer entity may have one referrer customer, so the relation is like a child-parent relation. [child-parent optional relationship entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461762/how-to-annotate-a-parent-child-relationship-with-code-first)

Comment: In this link, it is explained when a parent-child relationship with `PrimaryKey`. But in my case, I have to change model class which is not feasible for me.

Comment: You should remove the `ReferrerCode` and instead, use `ReferrerCustomerId` as an optional foreign key that refers to the ReferrerCustomer (child-parent relationship). This is the right design because you are making a repeative field.