# ForeignKey in child visible on parent in one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've got two entities with one-to-one relationship, let's call them `Parent` and `Child`. In the database, the `Child` table has a FK to `Parent`.

What I need to achieve is to have a navigation property to `Child` on `Parent`. The project doesn't use Fluent API, but uses attributes.

Can someone help me? In the end, I want to be able to use it something like this:

```
Set<Parent>().Include(w => w.ChildNavigationProp)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461762/how-to-annotate-a-parent-child-relationship-with-code-first. Hope this helps

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

here you have full example of relationships in ef core. First examples shows how ef core does it by default implicitlly, but you can do it manually by fluent api or data annotations.